# How to automatically Start an activity at the same time for all clients?

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

I am making an android game app with java in which users have options to register for a game and play the game when it starts at a time in the future (say game starts at 5:00 PM today). **My problem is suppose 100 users have registered for the game that starts in at exact 5:00PM , then how to start the same activity/intent for all 100 users at 5:00 PM automatically if the user has opened the app?** If the user has not opened the app I give him a notification "that game is about to begin, Kindly play your registered game." What should I use to accomplish this? Should I use Alarmmanager, job scheduler, Workmanager, Or Broadcast Receiver? And how to correctly use them for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services).

This method will help you to auto open the app from a notification service or other services

```
private void autoOpenApp() {
    ///----Auto open app----\\\
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
            PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
            PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "app:WakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire(10000);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YOUR_ACTIVITY_WHICH_YOU_WANT_TO_OPEN.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

}
```

add permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

add `android:launchMode` and `android:showOnLockScreen` in the manifest inside `<activity.../>` tag

```
    <activity
        android:name="YOUR_ACTIVITY_WHICH_YOU_WANT_TO_OPEN"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:showOnLockScreen="true"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer to this.. I would like to know what is 10000 in wakeLock.acquire(10000) ? Can I put the time remaining(in milliseconds) since the Game starts  in place of 10000?

Comment: No,
Acquires the wake lock with a timeout.
Ensures that the device is on at the level requested when the wake lock was created. The lock will be released after the given timeout expires.

read this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock